# Building rust project in docker causes Cargo to get stuck downloading dependencies

Tags: docker, rust, dockerfile, rust-cargo

I have a project that attempts to build a docker image with a rust binary, however it gets stuck when i tries to use Cargo to download the binaries. Running the image with `-it`, volume-mounting the src and then running `cargo build` manually works fine.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:1.31.1 AS builder
# Install protoc
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip \
    && PROTOC_ZIP=protoc-3.3.0-linux-x86_64.zip \
    && curl -OL https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.3.0/$PROTOC_ZIP \
    && unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local bin/protoc \
    && rm -f $PROTOC_ZIP

COPY . .
RUN cargo test
RUN cargo test --release -- --ignored
RUN cargo build --release

FROM debian
COPY --from=builder /target/release/brqueue /bin/brqueue
RUN chmod +x /bin/brqueue
CMD ["/bin/brqueue"]
```

I have tried with both rust 1.31.1 and 1.30.0.

Running the build end up with a log something like this:

```
N:\dev\rust\brqueue>docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  303.1kB
Step 1/10 : FROM rust:1.31.1 AS builder
 ---> d6daf33d7ea6
Step 2/10 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip     && PROTOC_ZIP=protoc-3.3.0-linux-x86_64.zip     && curl -OL https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.3.0/$PROTOC_ZIP     && unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local bin/protoc     && rm -f $PRO
TOC_ZIP
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cc1d7cab5aca
Step 3/10 : COPY . .
 ---> 909bab589108
Step 4/10 : RUN cargo test
 ---> Running in 6a9d0bc0a3f1
    Updating crates.io index
 Downloading crates ...
  Downloaded log v0.4.6
  Downloaded crossbeam v0.6.0
  Downloaded futures v0.1.25
  Downloaded serde_derive v1.0.82
  Downloaded bincode v1.0.1
  Downloaded serde v1.0.82
  Downloaded futures-cpupool v0.1.8
  Downloaded uuid v0.7.1
  Downloaded tls-api v0.1.20
  Downloaded bytes v0.4.11
  Downloaded tls-api-native-tls v0.1.20
  Downloaded byteorder v1.2.7
  Downloaded protobuf v2.2.0
  Downloaded protoc-rust v2.2.0
  Downloaded cfg-if v0.1.6
  Downloaded quote v0.6.10
  Downloaded crossbeam-utils v0.6.3
  Downloaded native-tls v0.1.5
  Downloaded crossbeam-epoch v0.7.0
  Downloaded proc-macro2 v0.4.24
  Downloaded crossbeam-channel v0.3.4
  Downloaded num_cpus v1.9.0
  Downloaded iovec v0.1.2
  Downloaded rand v0.5.5
  Downloaded syn v0.15.23
  Downloaded parking_lot v0.7.0
  Downloaded lazy_static v1.2.0
  Downloaded unicode-xid v0.1.0
  Downloaded rand v0.6.1
  Downloaded crossbeam-deque v0.6.3
  Downloaded env_logger v0.6.0
  Downloaded tempdir v0.3.7
  Downloaded arrayvec v0.4.10
  Downloaded protoc v2.2.0
  Downloaded smallvec v0.6.7
  Downloaded rand_core v0.2.2
  Downloaded protobuf-codegen v2.2.0
  Downloaded memoffset v0.2.1
  Downloaded scopeguard v0.3.3
  Downloaded openssl v0.9.24
  Downloaded lazy_static v0.2.11
  Downloaded libc v0.2.45
  Downloaded rustc_version v0.2.3
  Downloaded atty v0.2.11
  Downloaded rand_chacha v0.1.0
  Downloaded regex v1.1.0
  Downloaded parking_lot_core v0.4.0
  Downloaded remove_dir_all v0.5.1
  Downloaded rand_pcg v0.1.1
  Downloaded unreachable v1.0.0
  Downloaded lock_api v0.1.5
  Downloaded rand_core v0.3.0
  Downloaded nodrop v0.1.13
  Downloaded rand_xorshift v0.1.0
  Downloaded humantime v1.2.0
  Downloaded termcolor v1.0.4
  Downloaded void v1.0.2
  Downloaded thread_local v0.3.6
  Downloaded aho-corasick v0.6.9
  Downloaded bitflags v0.9.1
  Downloaded owning_ref v0.4.0
  Downloaded rand v0.4.3
  Downloaded semver v0.9.0
  Downloaded rand_hc v0.1.0
  Downloaded memchr v2.1.2
  Downloaded openssl-sys v0.9.39
  Downloaded foreign-types v0.3.2
  Downloaded quick-error v1.2.2
  Downloaded rand_isaac v0.1.1
  Downloaded utf8-ranges v1.0.2
  Downloaded version_check v0.1.5
  Downloaded regex-syntax v0.6.4
  Downloaded pkg-config v0.3.14
  Downloaded foreign-types-shared v0.1.1
  Downloaded semver-parser v0.7.0
  Downloaded cc v1.0.26
  Downloaded stable_deref_trait v1.1.1
  Downloaded ucd-util v0.1.3
```

Which crate it stops on doesn't seem stable, but is roughly within the same 10 packages.

The full project code is here: https://github.com/zlepper/brqueue if that is any help.

Comment: that obviously a docker problem, I don't see how we could help you. BTW, `COPY . .` look useless.

Comment: I would rather ask here, before I go poke docker people with a bug report, that was just me having messed up.

Comment: My guess is that it hangs _after_ downloading the crates. The command that hangs is `cargo test`, so it looks like the tests are taking a long time. The order of the "Downloaded <crate>" messges is non-deterministic, since crates are downloaded in parallel, so it may look like it's hanging for a different crate every time.

Comment: I just noticed that after downloading the crates, the next step is compiling the crates, which according to the messages did not start yet. This is a surprising problem, and I don't know what's causing it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter if I do test or build, but you are right, it might have finished downloading, but shouldn't it then start a compile for each package?

Comment: Stargateur, your comment with COPY . . being useless actually managed to lead me to solve it. Changing it to `COPY . /root/brqueue` instead makes everything work flawlessly. So i might be cargo trying to compile everything in the entire container, including rust itself again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So turns out the issue was with the `COPY . .` command, as it just copied everything into `/`, which was then attempted to be compiled (At least that's my belief).

Comment: Helped me as well. Could you please edit your answer including your insight from comment under question? This is what really helped me.